# Creating 1000 views in a scroll view takes time

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I am creating 1000 views in a scrollview. This takes more time to load the view.

```
wordsDetails *wordsObj;
for(int i = 0; i<arrayOfWords.count;i++) {
    UIView *viewForDisplay = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320*i, 0, 320, 440)];
    UILabel *wordLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 40, 240, 40)];
    wordLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    wordLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    wordLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Didot" size:24.0];
    wordsObj = [arrayOfWords objectAtIndex:i];
    wordLabel.text = wordsObj.word;//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sdssds - %i",i];
    [viewForDisplay addSubview:wordLabel];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 240, 100)];
    textView.text  = wordsObj.meaning;
    textView.editable = NO;
    textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Didot" size:20.0];
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [viewForDisplay addSubview:textView];
    [fScrollView addSubview:viewForDisplay];
}
```

Is there a way to call this in thread.

Comment: have a look at this link https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it like this. Use a cell-based scrollview subclass (table view or collection view) or roll your own. Your content is the width of the screen so there is absolutely no need to load 1000 screens worth of content at once.

With the cell-based views you only create as many as are needed to show a screen, and these are recycled and reconfigured as new content comes on screen.

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating 1000 views in a scrollview.

Don't do that. The user can't possibly *use* 1000 views all at once, so don't create them all at once. There are some good videos from WWDC 2010, 2011, and 2012 that cover tiling the content in scroll views -- take a look at those for some great ideas.

The scroll view delegate gets messages as the scroll view's content moves, and you can use those messages to add content just in time for it to scroll onto the screen and remove it after it has scrolled off. This is essentially what UITableView and UICollectionView do, and you can use either of them as jrturton suggests, or you can follow the same pattern yourself.

This will not only speed up the creation of your scroll view, it'll also make your scrolling smoother and consume much less memory than you would need otherwise.